# how to resolve Permission denied (publickey) when maven release used

Tags: git, maven, maven-plugin, release, maven-release-plugin

i have this error message :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.2:prepare (default-cli) on project portail: Unable to
commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-push command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] Permission denied (publickey).
[ERROR] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

i dont understand. I use this command maven :

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -Dtag=xxx-2.1-RC03 -DreleaseVersion=2.1-RC03 -DdevelopmentVersion=2.2-SNAPSHOT
```

and i have the half of result because i can see the first push `[maven-release-plugins] prepare release xxx-2.1.0-RC03`
but i can not see the artifact 2.1.0-RC03 on my nexus.

If i use maven release on Jenkins on same project the build will success fully...

Comment: What URL to git repository is being used in those two jobs? Are you sure that Jenkins job is using your key configured in Jenkins?

Comment: you push me on the best way, and i saw my scm configuration (in pom) and i change "jenkins" (developerConnection/push section) with my username, that works ! (sorry for my bad english!)

Comment: I'm glad that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on provided information it's not possible to give you the exact answer, but I'd expect that the problem lurks somewhere in:

- jenkins job confinguration,
- maven configuration of the project.

As you stated in the comment, the latter is true in this case.

Comment: Yes, like i said in comment, i needed to upgrade my developerConnection/push section configuration with my ssh key! thx