# How do I push a release to github with the maven release plugin?

Tags: git, maven, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm able to push to my Gihub repository just fine with SSH but I'm getting an error when I try to push with the maven release plugin at prepare stage:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:3.0.0-M1:prepare (default-cli) on project netbeans-visual-diff-standalone: Unable to commit file

Caused by: org.apache.maven.shared.release.scm.ReleaseScmCommandException: Unable to commit files
Provider message:
The git-push command failed.
Command output:
nbauma109@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I followed all the steps here to create public/private keys, upload the public key to my github account and add private key to ssh agent :

https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

I updated the maven POM with release plugin configuration and scm connection settings :

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:https://github.com/nbauma109/netbeans-visual-diff-standalone.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:ssh://git@github.com/nbauma109/netbeans-visual-diff-standalone.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/nbauma109/netbeans-visual-diff-standalone</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
<distributionManagement>
   <repository>
     <id>pkg.github.com</id>
     <name>GitHub nbauma109 Apache Maven Packages</name>
     <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/nbauma109/mvn-repo</url>
   </repository>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
      <configuration>
        <tagBase>ssh://git@github.com/nbauma109/netbeans-visual-diff-standalone/tags</tagBase>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.scm.id>github.com</project.scm.id>
</properties>
```

In the MAVEN user ~/.m2/settings.xml file, I included the ssh key information with private key location, passphrase and pasted the contents of the public key inside the "contents" tag :

```
  <servers>
    <server>
        <id>github.com</id>
        <username>git</username>
        <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_ed25519</privateKey>
        <passphrase>censored</passphrase>
        <filePermissions>664</filePermissions>
        <directoryPermissions>775</directoryPermissions>
        <configuration>
          <knownHostsProvider implementation="org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.ssh.knownhost.SingleKnownHostProvider">
            <hostKeyChecking>yes</hostKeyChecking>
            <contents>ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIDqdqJcRAZvJvTVWRXBlFB/c+w8pZPFRoWNXKFp6CSTV nbauma109@github.com</contents>
          </knownHostsProvider>
        </configuration>
    </server>
    <server>
        <id>pkg.github.com</id>
        <username>nbauma109</username>
        <password>github_personal_token</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

In the knowns_hosts file, I added localhost and my IP.
I have 3 files under ~/.ssh :

- id_ed25519 (private key)
- id_ed25519.pub (public key)
- known_hosts

I launch the release the plugin with the following command inside git-bash after having added my key to the ssh agent with an ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 :

```
mvn -X -Dusername=git release:clean release:prepare release:perform
```

When I'm prompted for version and tag information, I just press enter to choose the defaults.

- release version : 2.0.1
- next development version : 2.0.2-SNAPSHOT

Also, I came across some similar post [how to resolve Permission denied (publickey) when maven release used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491079/how-to-resolve-permission-denied-publickey-when-maven-release-used) and the OP said he solved the issue by adding the public key to the developerConnection/push section inside the POM file but I've never seen such a thing and I don't think it's the place for that.

EDIT (after @VonC 's answer) : After changing the user from nbauma109 to git, and updating POM and maven settings.xml, I have now two repos, github.com with private key authentication, and pkg.github.com with person token authentication. Now I can push the tag to github.com and I'm able to push the package to Github packages (pkg.github.com) provided my personal token github_personal_token has 'write package' permission.

Now my issue is that I've pushed a package that nobody can have access to without authentication and my release tag is empty of binaries that other projects could use. Do I have no other option than re-upload my binaries manually to the release tag using the Github web GUI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you see `nbauma109@github.com`, you can be sure an SSH push will fail (from command-line or maven)

A GitHub SSH URL would *always* use the remote user '`git`': `git@github.com:...`, never the actual GitHub user account name: your public key registered to said GitHub account is suppose to authenticate you.

So start testing with:

```
<username>git</username>
```

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944752/how-do-i-push-a-release-to-github-with-the-maven-release-plugin/66952795?noredirect=1#comment126996583_66952795) by the [OP Sybuser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8315843/sybuser)

> I have a solution *without* GitHub packages, which is to:
>
> - configure maven `release` plugin with `<goals>install</goals>`, and
> - use a GitHub action for the maven release (for example [`qcastel/github-actions-maven-release`](https://github.com/qcastel/github-actions-maven-release))
> - and a GitHub action for GitHub release (for example [`marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases`](https://github.com/marvinpinto/action-automatic-releases)).

Comment: Ok now it manages to push a tag but now it's stuck at pushing (with no error) at pushing to Github packages. I will update my question accordingly.

Comment: @Sybuser That is a separate question entirely though.

Comment: @Sybuser did you manage to fully solve the issue? I'm stuck with a similar one

Comment: I have a solution without GitHub packages which is to configure maven release plugin with <goals>install</goals> and use a GitHub action for the maven release (for example qcastel) and a GitHub action for GitHub release (for example marvinpinto). If you still want to use GitHub packages, sorry, can't help you there.

Comment: @Sybuser Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, with additional links.